# Difficulties with Bluebird Promise.bind()

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to call a chain of promises sequentially.  I would like to pass some state across all the promises.  I thought I'd be able to `bind()` my state but have been unable to get it working.  My sample code looks like:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
...
function op1(state) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}
function op2(state) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}
function op3(state) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}

function sequence(tasks, state) {
    var current = Promise.cast();
    for (var k = 0; k < tasks.length; ++k) {
        current = current.thenReturn().then(tasks[k]);
    }
    return current.thenReturn();
}

var state = { yadda: "yadda",
                      num:   0 };
var q = [ op1, op2, op3 ];

var p   = sequence( q, state );
var ret = p()
            .then( function(val) {
                console.log(val);
            })
            .catch ( function(val) {
                console.error(val);
            });
```

I've tried to simplify the problem to what I see in many example:

```
op1().bind(state).then(op2).then(op3);
```

However, this isn't working either.

I've also tried to change `sequence()` to the following (among various other things):

```
var current = Promise.cast().bind(state);
```

I am still very new to promises. I suspect I am missing something easy.  Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can `bind` Promises; you probably need to bind the functions within them.

Comment: Did you notice you're **not using the function arguments anywhere**??

Comment: @Hamms: It's bluebird, not native promises.

Comment: I apologize, yes, I forgot to scrub the function arguments when I posted, the function arguments were part of various attempts with `bind()`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's see what could be done.

We could start with binding `state` to each task.

```
function sequence(tasks, state) {
    var current = Promise.resolve();
    for (var k = 0; k < tasks.length; ++k) {
        const taskWithState = tasks[k].bind(state);
        current = current.then(taskWithState);
    }
    return current;
}
```

I've used `bind` to set `this` inside tasks to `state`, so:

```
function op1() {
    // this === state
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // this === window
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}
```

As You might expect, a function that we pass to Promise creates its own context, so `this` would not point to `state` like we want it to.

To bypass that issue we could either do an old trick with saving context in a variable (like `var that = this`) or we could just use arrow functions, which do not create their own context. With that in mind:

```
function op1() {
    // this === state
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // this === state
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}
```

### All together now

```
function op1() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}

function op2() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}

function op3() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.num += 1;
        resolve();
    });
}

function sequence(tasks, state) {
    let current = Promise.resolve();
    for (let k = 0; k < tasks.length; ++k) {
        const taskWithState = tasks[k].bind(state);
        current = current.then(taskWithState);
    }
    return current;
}

var state = { yadda: "yadda", num:  0 };
var q = [ op1, op2, op3 ];

sequence(q, state)
  .then(() => console.log(state))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed write up.  Your solution worked well.  I did try to bind to the "task", but did not realize the `this` was changed within the Promise callback.